# SQL: Why does SYS.COLUMNS show my columns having different properties than what I set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added a table to a database with the following column names and datatypes

"ID" bigInt, "Description" nchar(11)

If I check the design view of the table, the datatypes of the columns are as I set them.

If I write a query that will get the columns in that table from SYS.COLUMNS the column properties are different e.g.(the max_length of description is 22, not 11)

Can someone explain why that is?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit) if that is relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The column `max_length` in [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) show the max length in bytes. [nchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) is double byte so 11 chars take 22 bytes.

If you want the number of characters you could use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

```
select COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```

Or you could use the function [COLUMNPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174968.aspx)

```
select name,
       columnproperty(object_id, name, 'charmaxlen') as charmaxlen
from sys.columns
where object_name(object_id) = 'YourTable'
```

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer when the site lets me. 
If I try to get the precision of a column from SYS.COLUMNS it gives me 0. Is there a way I can get back the number I set in the size with a query?

EDIT: The precision is only 0 for the description, it is 19 for bigint

Comment: precision only makes sense for non-precise numeric types (i.e. float, decimal).